# ejabberd mod_muc error joining a chat room (503)

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, multiuserchat

I've updated from ejabberd 15.04 to 15.07 and MUC stopped working. (I copied the exact same config file). I can create a room and change options normally but when I send an invitation and the user tries to join I get the message 503 - Service Unavailable.

This is the muc config that was working fine before and stopped working:

```
mod_muc: 
  db_type: odbc 
  host: "chat.@HOST@" 
  access: muc 
  access_create: muc_admin 
  access_persistent: muc 
  access_admin: muc_admin
```

Any idea of what might be happening? I've read some stuff about DNS but to be honest this is all local and nothing has changed related with the network from one version to another

Here's the [log](https://gist.github.com/nunohorta/9aaf04ff5c2d333f4e55). The first part is when I send the direct invitation and then accept to join the room using Adium.

Here is ejabberd config file: https://gist.github.com/nunohorta/b7e97503d3b7eb2921e0

I cleared the current database and MUC is working again.

Comment: You should look at the log. Usually the answer is there. Usually it is a config file problem. You do not show the whole config file, but your snippet depends on a database being configured and being in a modules section.

Comment: Hi Mickael. I edited the post with the log file. It fails after 384 Finding connection for {<<"localhost">>,<<"chat.localhost">>}...but I'm not sure why. I mean, what changed from one version to another. I literally copied the ejabberd.yml file after the update. I'll update with the config as soon as possible.

Comment: Check the whole log file, it is incomplete. Start errors are at the beginning.

Comment: Could you look at the beginning of the log file and share it ? You need to see the start messages to see what is wrong.

Comment: you mean when the server and modules starts right? I will share it as soon as possible

Comment: Yes, i think the full logs usually help.

Comment: I cleared the current database and everything works again. I'm wondering how will I handle future update when I can't simply clear the database. Is there any merging process?